# filter for key-value pair in cassandra wide rows

Tags: cassandra, wide-column-store, nosql

I am trying to model time series data with many sensors (> 50k) with cassandra. As I would like to do filtering on multiple sensors at the same time, I thought using the following (wide row) schema might be suitable:

```
CREATE TABLE data(
 time timestamp, 
 session_id int, 
 sensor text, 
 value float, 
 PRIMARY KEY((time, session_id), sensor)
);
```

If every sensor value was a column in an RDBMS, my query would ideally look like:

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE sensor_1 > 10 AND sensor_2 < 2;
```

Translated to my cassandra schema, I assumed the query might look like:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE 
  sensor = 'sensor_1' AND 
  value > 10 AND 
  sensor = 'sensor_2' AND 
  value < 2;
```

I now have two problems:

1. cassandra tells me that I can filter on the sensor column only
   once:

> sensor cannot be restricted by more than one relation if it
>       includes an Equal

2. Obviously, the filter on value doesn't make sense at the moment. I wouldn't know how to express the relationship
   between sensor and value in the query in order to filter multiple
   columns in the same (wide) row.

I do know that a solution to the first question would be to use CQL's `IN` clause. This however doesn't solve the second problem.

Is this scenario even suitable for cassandra?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use IN clause [here](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/a-deep-look-to-the-cql-where-clause).
So your query would be like this:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
WHERE time = <time> and session_id = <session id> 
    AND sensor IN ('sensor_1', 'sensor_2') 
    AND value > 10 AND value < 2
```

Comment: But how would i make sure that the value for 'sensor_1' would be greater than 10 and the value for 'sensor_2' would be less than 2? It seems to me that actually any of the 50k sensor values could match that criteria.

Comment: I understand your question now. You have to design your table with an select driven approach. If you share what information you want to get we can suggest a more suitable table design for you.

Comment: I want to find all sessions in which sensors have specific values at the same  point in time. For example, I want to find the sessions in which the temperature was above 10 degrees and the humidity was less than 40% at the same time.